# Convert .psd into .png without loosing shading and lightening

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photo-editing

So I do not own Photoshop, but got a .psd file from my client to work with. 
I managed to use a online converter and get this .png out of it.
[image]

What I additionally need though is the conversion of only Layer 1 (which is the Leona text) upsized a little bit and/or only Layer 4. I tried to do that with Paint.net and the .psd extension and other image programs like gimp, but I am only able to get out this:

[image]

I do not know how the shading and lightening is rendered, anybody has an idea how I could solve this and succesfully convert layer1 and/or layer2 without loosing the text effects?

Here is the .psd file:
https://mega.co.nz/#!rh0nVLDK!NMSC-dlTJN46njxR6cwe-k2mXJJ1lGOUpqSniXc_q3M

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Photoshop the effects of your original can easily be reproduced with default filters included in Gimp (here 2.8. on Linux):

1. Filters > Decor > Add Bevel:

   [image]
2. Filters > Light & Shadow > Drop Shadow: *Grey heavy blurred*

   [image]
3. Filters > Light & Shadow > Drop Shadow: *Black little blurred*

   [image]

We can further fine-tune the results by using different settings for each
filter.

Example working on your original file (directly imported to Gimp) using bevel and a single drop shadow:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Adobe's website](http://www.adobe.com/downloads.html) and download Photoshop.  They have a free trial and you won't have to mess around with random workarounds and everything else; you'll be able to save it normally in Photoshop.

Comment: I actually tried to avoid this, since I am mostly working on Linux, but its probably the best way still. When I am working on PS and export the file into png the shading and light effects will be on the image? I am trying to understand where this is information is stored, or if I need to do a special rendering process.

Comment: If you open the psd in Photoshop, just hide the layers that you don't want in the png and then Save As.

Comment: I sadly fail to get the free trial version, since this strange cloude software which is required to download it, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Although this looks like an interesting logo, effects which are applied on it could be easily reproduced - opened in PhotShop CS2 / recently available as a free download. ,)